# Android Layout: fragment with listview layout is not fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-studio

I have this layout problem in fragments containing a listview; List view is not expanding to `match_parent`.

I have a list view with few items. The layout is showing only for the elements that don't cover the full screen.

I tried with **match_parent** in all my layouts but I'm still unable to solve the issue.

**Below is my fragmentlayout with list view**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/borevalues" 
       >


        <ListView android:id="@+id/listofboreranges" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null" 
            android:scrollbars="none"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Below is my container layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is how i am invoking fragment with listview**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
                    ft.hide(FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.lastElement());
                    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, boreranges);
                    FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.push(boreranges);
                    ft.commit();
```

Any solution for this?

It looks as below

[image]

Fragment `A` has this orange and green button that when I click on, it will go to Fragment `B` which has the listview.
I want the listview in fragment B full screen and cover green and orange.

Comment: can you post your screen image

Comment: @PhanVănLinh Sorry i cannot share screen shot publicly..whats happening is when i am going from one fragment to this list fragment ,the listview covers only half screen as it has only 4 items ,in background i can still see old fragment from where i invoke this list fragment.

Comment: maybe you can hide some part in your screen that you don't want to publish

Comment: can you bound your listview width and height

Comment: @PhanVănLinh What do u mean my bound?.I am need full screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105787/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-hari86).

Answer (score 0):

try using this code

```
MyFragment boreranges= new MyFragment();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.mainframe, boreranges);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Thats how i am doing it previously

Comment: in xml to test put background color for listview and check in design it will cover whole screen or not, pls check n let me know...

Comment: Hey i put red color to listview in xml , but iam unable to see re when i run the app, what is happening

Comment: its coming in design view??? i mean in studio itself there is design and text for xml, check in design that is visible and it covers full screen or not..?

Comment: Yeah in studio it is showing red background with full screen, but when i run in device iam not seeing any red

Comment: r u setting adapter to listview properly? or else post the fragment and activity code i will check...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105788/discussion-between-naveen-shriyan-and-hari86).